# Output by Group - maybe foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am on a project where I put JSON data from a external API to the MySQL database. This works fine.

The output with `GROUPING` and `ORDER BY` is not really how I want it

What I got so far :

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (task))
FROM time_summary
GROUP BY projectName
ORDER BY clientName
```

The table looks like this:

```
id      clientName          project             task
1       firm One            online              banner
2       firm One            print               folder
3       firm Two            water               with gas
4       firm One            online              website
5       firm Two            water               with gas
6       firm Two            water               with gas
```

Output is:
**firmOne**
 online
  banner, website
 print
  folder

**Now the Question:**
The grouped tasks are seperated by commas.

I have a while loop output - but I need each task in a new line (grouped by the project) like

**firmOne**
 online
  banner
  website
 print
  folder

PHP Code is like this one:

```
$new = 1;

$last_client = 'initial';

while($row = _mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    if($last_client != $row['clientName'] && $last_client != 'initial') {
        echo '<div class="cb h20"></div>';
        $new = 1;
    }

    if($new == 1) {
        echo  '<span class="yellow-small">' . $row["clientName"] . '</span>';
        $new = 0;
    }
    ?>
    <b><?=$row['projectName'];?></b><br>

      <?=$row['GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (task))'];?>
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Column names and code dont seem to match????

Comment: Sorry, just writing too fast :D
i fix it

Comment: `SELECT *, .... GROUP BY projectName` is bad use of SQL https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP BY` is invalid SQL. Even if MySQL accepts it before version 5.7.5, [the values it returns are indeterminate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregating the tasks into CSV only to then split them apart again in your PHP code does not sound like a good option to me.  Would the following simple query not give you the data you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    clientName,
    project,
    task
FROM time_summary
ORDER BY
    clientName,
    project,
    task
```

This query would report, for each client and project, only the distinct list of tasks.  Now you can iterate over this result set in your PHP code to generate the output you want:

```
$client = null;
$project = null;

while ($row = _mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $curr_client = $row['clientName'];
    if ($curr_client != $client) {
        echo $curr_client."<br>";
        $client = $curr_client;
    }

    $curr_project = $row['projectName'];
    if ($curr_project != $project) {
        echo "  ".$curr_project."<br>";
        $project = $curr_project;
    }

    echo "    ".$row['task']."<br>";
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

As a disclaimer, I focused on the query and presentation logic needed to get the display you wanted, not on the PHP code.  That might be the topic of another discussion altogether.

Here is a link to a small PHP demo which shows that the presentation logic is reliable:

## Rextester

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm sure there are all sorts of bad PHP things going on in the OP and possibly my answer.  I am focusing on the query and the presentation logic.

Comment: It is a function for pdo .. function _mysql_fetch_array(){
 return $GLOBALS['_pdo_s']->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

Comment: i would give you an upvote, but i have not the required reputation points yet

Answer (score 0):

If you simply add the line

`$holder = str_replace(",", "<br>", $row['GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (taskName))']);`

Right before your 
    `<?=$row['GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (taskName))'];?>`

And then replace your line

`<?=$row['GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (taskName))'];?>`

with

`<?=$holder;?>`

This replaces the comma with a `<br>` and will force the second value to the next line.